# How to partition postgresql in django rest framework

Tags: postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to partition a table in django rest framework which uses the postgresql database.

I am not being able to import Architect and `django-postgres-extra` packages. Can someone please help me to partition the table as I have a stock dataset with every stocks daily historical data, also each stock data will be added everyday. So I want to partition the table by stock Names so that each stock has its own table for faster lookup.

Answer (score 1):

I'm can't give a detailed answer, since the model is not mentioned, yet I can give you a lead - use Django's magnificent [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/#topics-db-aggregation) functions✨ (like SQL's GROUP BY) you can aggregate by the stock name, and have all its related properties.
e.g. something like `Stocks.objects.values(stock_name)`

I hope my Breadcrumb trail will help you...

Comment: Thanks, helped me with other problem, but this current problem requires something else, I need to partition it at the database using postgresql commands.